# LabVIEW: handling exceptions thrown from C# on VI

Tags: c#, .net, error-handling, labview

I am writing a labVIEW VI to be able to handle exceptions thrown from C# library. I don't know how to use the error cluster to read exception messages and also how to handle to exit the application.

I wrote the C# code in such way:

```
// Make use of generic System library calls in this code.
using System.ComponentModel;

// Define the namespace for the following classes.
namespace NETEvents
{
    // ProduceMyEvent is a class that will fire the event.
    public class ProduceMyEvent : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //Declare an internal variable. We will use this to fire events upon a changed value.
        //Note that this value is private to the ProduceMyEvent class.
        private int x;
        // Fire the event when the value of x changes.
        public int xValue
        {
            //Get the value of x.
            get { return x; }
            //Set x to be the new value and fire off the new event!
            set { x = value;

                if (x < 0) {
                    throw new System.Exception("x must be larger than 0 \n");
                }

                OnPropertyChanged("xValue"); }
        }

        // INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

With this code if x is set as negative from VI then an exception is thrown. But with my labview implementation shown below, the exception isn't caught; the error status is not true and also the source is empty. How do I use the error cluster to be able to read the exception thrown from C# ?

[image]

Comment: Where are you passing the reading the value returned from your c# code in labview? Where you do that, just use a [case structure, or a selector](https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z000000P81mSAC), to pass a new error cluster with the details you want.

Answer (score 0):

Exception handling is explained in detail here: https://forums.ni.com/t5/LabVIEW/Catch-Exception-in-c-with-Net-Assembly-Built-in-Labview/td-p/3360501